# Is there a 'NotImplementedAttribute' in .NET?

Tags: .net

#### Duplicate

> [Custom Compiler Warnings in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

I'd like to be able to tag my code with a `NotImplementedAttribute` and have the compiler either give a warning or an error at build time if the method is used.

I know there is the `ObsoleteAttribute`, but that communicates something very different.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can do anything similar to `ObsoleteAttribute`. Howerver, you can add `#warning` directive to your code, so that compiler will emit a warning. However, it will be there until you remove the directive.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here:

[Custom Compiler Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)