# Generating a custom compile time warning C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, custom-attributes, postsharp

I'm using VS2008 and would like to create a compile time warning / error based on custom attributes on a property (if it is possible).

There are two cases which interest me currently:

```cs
[MyAttribute (typeof(MyClass)]
```

Where `MyClass` has to implement an interface. Currently I assert this in the constructor of the attribute, however this doesn't make it easy to track down, due to the nature of the stack trace:

```cs
public MyAttribute (Type MyClassType)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(
        typeof(MyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(MyClassType),
        "Editor must implement interface: " + typeof(MyInterface).Name);
}
```

The second case which interests me is where I have a type defined in an attribute, if that type implements an interface, then a warning should be displayed if another attribute isn't present.

I.E. `if (MyClass.Implements(SomeInterface) && !Exists(SomeAttibute)) {  Generate Warning }`

```cs
[MyAttribute(typeof(MyClass)] 
// Comment next line to generate warning
[Foo ("Bar")]
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).

I've once done it, and explained how to do it [here](http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I had looked at post sharp before (for another problem) and decided it against it, however now I think I will be re-evaluating ;)

Comment: I have just discovered a bit of an issue - it seems that GetCustomAttributes() no longer returns the attribute when it derives from PostSharp.Laos.OnMethodInvocationAspect rather than System.Attribute

Comment: You mean it returns System.Attribute ?  Can't you cast it to your own attribute ?  (GetCustomAttributes always returns an array of System.Attribute AFAIK, so you always have to cast i think ?

Comment: No, PostShap strips the Aspect attribute out of the metadata when it does its post compilation stage (ILDSAM confirms this). I did get around it by using CompoundAspect rather than OnMethodInvocationAspect as the base class. Then overriding ProvideAspects to re-insert itself into the metadata. -Phew-. Thanks Again :)

Comment: I have just discovered that using '[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Property, PersistMetaData = true)]' removes the need for the CompoundAspect.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels - All of the code on your blog is a broken link. Could you post the code here?

Comment: This is a link to answer, not an answer itself.