# .NET : Get property name in attribute

Tags: .net, attributes

```
[MyAttribute()]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In `MyAttribute` I need to know the name of associated property, is it possible?

**EDIT:**

I need to use it in text formatting.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need it and what you would use it for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Usually you would use [reflection to read attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) applied on a given property, so you already know the property. Example:

```
var properties = typeof(SomeType).GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
    if (attributes.Count > 0)
    {
        // look at property.Name here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, may be i'm looking on the problem from opposite end than i should.

Comment: Yes, you start by a type, then get the properties and finally read the custom attributes applied to a given property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) aspect to do the job. I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420143/generating-a-custom-compile-time-warning-c) a while back, which was almost the same thing. You can see comments on the answer for more info about some of the implications that you might encounter.