# Some compiler help for "kind of" public methods in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is anyone aware of any attribute (analogous to [Obsolete]) or similar mechanism to ask the compiler to raise a warning if a particular class is referenced (at design-time) by other projects?  Note I cannot make it 'internal' because I'm databinding to System.* (or 3rd-party) controls so they have to be public.

Note I use [Obsolete] as an analogy, the class is not obsolete.  I just want compiler warnings for out-of-project design-time references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Compiler Warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

Comment: please show some examples of references that are ok and references that are not...

Comment: @RobertLevy Not a duplicate.  I want the warning to be raised based on whether the reference is internal or from other user projects.

Comment: @AlanR Apparently this is doable using PostSharp. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420143/generating-a-custom-compile-time-warning-c-sharp

Comment: @M.Babcock very interesting.  put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420143/generating-a-custom-compile-time-warning-c-sharp), it looks like it would be doable using [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). [Here is a link](http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html) from the answer that describes some detail which might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I could find -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx