# IDE underlining custom attributes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ide, attributes, colors

I have a custom attribute...

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)]
public class Refactor : System.Attribute
{
    private string _message;

    public Refactor()
    {
        _message = string.Empty;
    }

    public Refactor(string message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }               
}
```

Applied to

```
[Refactor("this should be less rubbish")]
public virtual void RubbishMethod()    
{    
…    
}
```

Now when someone makes a call to `RubbishMethod` I'd like the IDE (vs2008) to underline that call in a deep brown colour, similar to if I mark as Obsolete you get a green wave line. Is this possible? I've been racking my brain and hitting the google but I can't find how and where to do this.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings (short answer: no, `Obsolete` is magic)

Comment: ps attribute names should end in `Attribute` :)

Comment: You can *possibly* do it by writing your own IDE add-ins, but the amount of effort involved would be huge.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to write a VS extension. You would need to create a Classifier. The [Ook! language extension](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ookLanguage) has a good sample of making classifiers.