# Attribute to mark code

Tags: c#, .net

In c# there are attributes such as [obsolete] that create compiler warnings that will be shown in visual studio.

Is there an attribute that I can use to mark a method or a class with a comment that should be shown as a warning in visual studio when I compile?

Something like:

```
[TBD(Msg="Please change me after 2010 07 20")]
public void Foo(){
}
```

or is there a possibility that I can derive from System.Attribute and make my own attribute, configuring  visual studio so that it behaves as I described.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to all for your answers
I have accepted the answer from Robaticus because he showed me the solution that I really needed:

```
#warning Message
```

shows the desired message that I wanted and it does this without any overhead. Thanks!

However I searched in the wrong direction and therefore asked the wrong question. For those who are reading this post and are interested in an answer to the initial question, I find the link that Mark Rushakoff has
[posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings) 
is very interesting. In this post, Pablo Fernandez has shown a clever way using an attribute on an attribute to accomplish what I have asked for.

Comment: why not use obsolete with a date?

Comment: What's the difference between what you want and what `[Obsolete]` already does for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Compiler Warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

Comment: [Obsolete("Please change me after 2010 07 20")]

Comment: Obsolete shows a warning if I have a reference to the method. I want to have a warning that is shown as long as the attribute is attached to the method or class.

Comment: [Obsolete] works at the class level, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is do do a preprocessor directive:

```
#warning Please change this code after 2010 07 20
```

From [C# preprocessor directives - Error and warning information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#error-and-warning-information)

> `#warning` lets you generate a [CS1030](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1030) level one compiler warning from a specific location in your code. For example:

Comment: That's an unconditional warning, not a warning when the method/object is used.

Comment: Can the warning combined with [conditional compilation directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) something like  `#if <some-date> #else <nothing> #endif` . The compilte-time warning would start to show up as soon as the date is passed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329871(v=VS.71).aspx) to do this.

```
//Compiling error
[System.Obsolete("Obsolete use blah instead", true)]


//Compiling warning
[System.Obsolete("Obsolete use blah instead", false)]
```