# Is it possible to trigger conditional compiler warnings similar to "Obsolete", but with different meanings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a function which should only be used by a developer in special circumstances.

Unfortunately setting public / private doesn't really help, as it needs to be visible for use in many cases.

I have documented the function with xmldocs to give the developer a warning, but is it possible to output a compiler warning? Perhaps using an attribute, similar to marking a function as obsolete?

Or perhaps if someone has any useful architectural advice on steering people away from dangerous methods (i'm guessing this will probably be separate namespaces, inheritance etc?)

---

ADDITIONAL DETAIL

Thanks for the answers guys, lots of 1+'s from me :-)

It's also helped me clarify my question:

[Obsolete("my message")] is better in some ways to #warning, as it will only display a warning if the method is actually being used. However as ChrisF points out, it isn't actually an Obsolete method, so isn't really accurate.

Is there a middle ground between the functionality of [Obsolete("my message")] but without the meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Obsolete("Please don't use this")]
public void DodgyMethod()
{
}
```

> Any code that attempts to call the method will cause the compiler to issue a warning.

While it's not technically an obsolete method, the effect is the same.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF, I've added some additional detail.

Comment: @AlexKey - See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF,  I think obsolete is probably the best thing for the moment. I wonder if instead I need to come up with some sort of custom FxCop rule? Perhaps an experiment for another day :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#warning ...`

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I've added some additional detail

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio you can throw errors and warnings like this.

```
#warning This line is a compiled warning
```

I am not sure if you can do it conditional, but this will throw a warning when compiling.

Comment: Thanks @Schalk, I've added some additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is to write a small Roslyn Analyzer and ship that with your library. That way you can generate custom code inspections and that also allows the developer to suppress your warning with a proper Reason using the Suppress attribute.

Examples can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn879356.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, a nice new modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[Obsolete("Don't use this outside of whatever")]` to the method.

Comment: Thanks @Slaks I've added some additional detail

Answer (score 0):

Using [Obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) is indeed a good solution.

And you can still call this method yourself, by disabling the warning just for the call:

```csharp
#pragma warning disable CS0618
DodgyMethod();
#pragma warning restore CS0618
```