# how can I create [experimental] tag in c# which throws a compiler warning

Tags: c#

In c# I can mark some functions as obsolete by doing

```
[Obsolete]
void Foo()
{}
```

this tell the compiler to throw warning if I am using this function.

I want to create my own tag [Experimental] which just as obsolete throw a warning telling the user who build the code that this function is not well tested and using it may result in troubles.

Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: As far as I remember you can pass a custom warning message to Obsolete attribute. You can mark the code as Obsolete but in the message tell that the code is experimental.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I updated the header, so that it's more clear... seems that people are answering just how to create attributes and somebody were downvoting them for that. :/

Answer (score 16):

> I want to create my own attribute `[Experimental]` which just as `[Obsolete]` does makes the compiler produce a warning. Is it possible to do this?

No, sorry.  `Obsolete` is a very special attribute. The compiler has special-purpose code written for it. There is no extensible warning mechanism in C#.

If you would like to submit this suggestion to the Visual Studio team, you can do that at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/.

Answer (score 3):

The `Obsolete` attribute is special, as the C# compiler knows about it. You won't be able to create your own. The closest you could get would be to inherit from `ObsoleteAttribute` yourself, but the class is `sealed` so this is not possible.

As it is, you could mark your method as `[Obsolete("This method is not well tested.")]`. That's the best you can do.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? Unlike the other solutions, this *will* generate a compiler warning (or error, if the user chooses to so alter the base constructor call).

Comment: ObsoleteAttribute is marked as sealed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx), and cannot be inherited from. Also did not downvote...but that's probably why someone did.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but ObsoleteAttribute is sealed, this wont compile

Comment: this looks interesting... I would like to know why it got downvoted so many times though

Comment: @Maciej: Good catch (though I think you mean `sealed`; `final` is Java). I've altered the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Petr: Possibly because the `ObsoleteAttribute` class is `sealed` (which I unwisely hadn't bothered to check before answering).

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as an Attribute.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class Experimental: System.Attribute
{

}
```

Comment: How does that generate a compiler warning?

Comment: The question was updated before all of these answers. -3 for nothing.

Comment: It's pointless Chris.. this question was a goner from the start.. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Very true, some questions make you wish you'd never bothered!

Comment: Well, it looks like Microsoft took your advice (10 years later) and made the [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/experimental-attribute) in C# 12.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with PostSharp. There was a post about it on SO, but I ohly have the bookmark link now:

http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2008/08/locking-system-with-aspect-oriented.html

Look under *Compile Time Validation* in that page, it shows you how the author did it.

Further note: it involves a bit of plumbing code. Definitely not a "slap-it-in-to-the-project" variety of code.