# User defined compiler warning or error in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to have some code let the compiler generate a compile warning or error?

Maybe with Attributes?

**
Having the first answer and a few comments I realize my question is not as a clear as I expected and wanted it to be. I apologize. Hopefully all contributers are still with us.
**

So I am more looking towards an internal DSL.

S.Th. like

```
[MustAssign]
public string Val {get; set;]
```

Comment: Am pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0.aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel possibly, though it would help if you linked to a concrete example while marking as duplicate. There is this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings?lq=1 - which looks the same superficially but it seems to be a different question.

Comment: @CompuChip How that's is a different question? I fail to see that.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean [#warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3.aspx) ?

> **#warning** lets you generate a level one warning from a specific location in your code. For example:

```
#warning Deprecated code in this method.
```

And for errors, there is (you would never guess), [#error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0.aspx).

Comment: This is great and I did not know about that (+1). However - I edited my question - I would like to have some logic behind it - code that runs during compilation - and then creates Compiler Error

Comment: @MartinMeeser Did u find any solution??