# Forbid method attribute if other attribute is used

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, attributes

Is it possible to prevent an attribute to be applied to a given method (or class), if another attribute has already been specified?

For example, I would like to emit a compile time error or warning if attribute `B` is applied to a method where the attribute `A` has already been applied:

```
public class AttributeA : Attribute{}
public class AttributeB : Attribute{}

[A]
[B] // generates error or warning because of A
public void Foobar(){}
```

I don't think it's possible but it worth a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. A few months back I was looking to do something similar to what `ObsoleteAttribute` does by triggering a compiler warning for my custom attribute when I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154296/386703).