# Is there an option to generate compiler errors for impossible `OfType` calls

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn, compiler-warnings

Visual Studio is able to warn a user when certain type casts are impossible such as below

```cs
public class A{}
public class B{}

// ...

var x = new A();

// example 1
var y = (B)A; // Compiler Error CS0030

// example 2
if(x is B) // Compiler warning CS0184
```

I have looked but I cannot find any similar compile time checks available for the LINQ `OfType<T>` operator.

```cs
public class A{}
public class B{}

// ...

var x = new List<A>();
var y = x.OfType<B>(); // NO problem
```

Does anyone know if there is something already existing or would this need to be implemented as a [custom compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)?

Comment: it'd have to be custom

Comment: That would seem to require the compiler to know how `OfType<>` even works instead of treating it as any other method.

Comment: You'd probably need a custom analyzer. While probably irrelevant, as the question would still stand for some other LINQ methods, `OfType` is used exactly to filter irrelevant elements from a collection

Comment: Good point @BACON thanks for pointing that out. I was hoping that in the absence of something built in someone may know of something similar to [this custom analyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) but you make a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible as a general solution** (a custom analyzer can be written for specific cases though, such as your `OfType` example).

It's also not necessary though. The compiler error in your first example prevents a runtime `InvalidCastException`, and in your second example the warning indicates a predicate that's always `false`, and therefore any code in that `if` statement is unreachable - usually not the intent.

The `OfType` call has no possibility of a runtime failure. While there may be a minor performance benefit in your `OfType` example (as the check will invariably return an empty enumeration), since LINQ is lazily evaluated, the real performance benefit would be very minor, if any; but the *requirement for the compiler to understand the method's innner workings* to accomplish such task, is ...insanely hard to implement correctly! Compilers, even really advanced ones today, haven't learned to do that.

So, not possible, but that might be ok.

Comment: Note the C# compiler supports analyzers where somebody could explicitly teach it about OfType and add an error for precisely this. I'm not sure if somebody has already written such a thing though.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski yep, that is mentioned in my answer :)