# Warning when assigning non-nullable integer to nullable integer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullable, non-nullable

```
Nullable<int> a;
int b = 2;
a = b;
```

`a` is nullable integer.
`b` is NON-nullable integer.

I want to receive warning or error in Visual Studio when a NON-nullable integer is assigned to a nullable integer [`a = b`].  Is it possible?

Comment: Why should that be a warning or error? It's an operation that is always safe.

Comment: I don't know of any such warning and I doubt that it will ever exist, because it doesn't make much sense. If you really feel so inclined however, you could write your [own analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) for that.

Comment: Unless your nullable integer variable is always going to be null, then at some point it must be possible to assign a non-nullable integer value to it - so it does not make sense for it to be an error condition.

Comment: this link has answer [custom-compiler-warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#warning "NON-nullable integer is assigned to a nullable integer."
```

For more details refer the below link

[custom-compiler-warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)