# Create custom ObsoleteAttribute in C#

Tags: c#, attributes, obsolete

I'd like to use a `ObsoleteAttribute` with a custom const message in order to avoid copy/pasting the message everywhere.
For example here is my class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyObsoleteAttribute : Attribute
{
    private const string CustomMessage = "This is a custom warning message";
    public MyObsoleteAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CustomMessage);
    }
}
    
public class MyClass
{
    [MyObsolete]
    public string? Foo { get; set; }
    
    [MyObsolete]
    public string? Bar { get; set; }
    
    [MyObsolete]
    public string? FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to receive a warning in JetBrains Rider (or Visual Studio) when using such property in the same way as the `Obsolete` attribute with my `CustomMessage`.

I try overriding `ObsoleteAttribute` but it is `sealed`.

For example the following code should raise a warning (compile time) telling me "This is a custom warning message".

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
var foo = myClass.Foo;
var bar = myClass.Bar;
var fooBar = myClass.FooBar;
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings) but I couldn't find exactly an answer to this case: the closest answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154254/2965109) but it gives me warning on the property and not when using them.

Comment: Why not use `[Obsolete(ClassName.ConstantMessage)]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Compiler Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

Comment: @Bassinator very similar but I couldn't find exactly: the closest answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/154254/2965109 but it gives me warning on the property and not when using them

Comment: Well, you can always use the solution that @KlausGütter recommended, which is probably what I would do in your situation.

Comment: @KlausGütter You're right. I'd like to avoid the copy-pasting of "(ClassName.ConstantMessage)" using only an attribute but if it is impossibile your comment is the best way to have such behaviour. You can add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a string constant

```
public class ObsoleteReasons
{
    public const string Reason1 = "Don't use this";
}
```

and use it in the attribute

```
[Obsolete(ObsoleteReasons.Reason1)]
```